# convert date time epoch in miliseconds to UTC human readable format

Tags: linux, unix, shell-scripting, epoch-time

I am trying to convert date time in epoch to UTC human readable format, I have tried this and this gives me the result in CET but wrong result.

```
perl -e 'print scalar localtime(1549950859468 / 1000)
Tue Feb 12 06:54:19 2019
```

How should it be done in any help ?

Comment: I'm confused, why do you `/ 1000`? If I use this: `perl -e 'print scalar localtime(1554881524)'` it shows the correct time? 1554881524 is about _now_ of course.

Comment: @Lenniey You failed to understand the question :-)

Comment: hm...obviously :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would:

```
date -d @$((1549950859468 / 1000)) -u
```

do?